# Redrawing polylines on Google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, polyline

I have an application, doing a lot of redraws of a polyline (about 4 redraws per second).
Code for drawing the polyline:

```
            plo = new PolylineOptions().geodesic(true)
                    .color(Color.WHITE)
                    .width(4f)
                    .zIndex(0);
            plo.add(lineVector.position);
            plo.add(SphericalUtil.computeOffset(lineVector.position, 1000,lineVector.bearing));
            PredictionLine = mMap.addPolyline(plo);
```

The last Polyline is removed from the map before drawing the new one with:

```
        PredictionLine.remove();
```

This works perfectly, but only for some time. After a while, I get the message:

### The process com.google.process.gapps has stopped. OK?

I can click ok and the application works again normally, but also only for a limited time. Then suddenly the whole application crashes. Looking at the log returns the following:

```
07-23 10:41:32.838   12180-6237/app.skynavigator.android.skynavigator A/art﹕ art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:98] JNI ERROR (app bug): global reference table overflow (max=51200)
07-23 10:41:32.838   12180-6237/app.skynavigator.android.skynavigator A/art﹕ art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:98] global reference table dump:
07-23 10:41:32.838   12180-6237/app.skynavigator.android.skynavigator A/art﹕ art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:98]   Last 10 entries (of 51200):
07-23 10:41:32.838   12180-6237/app.skynavigator.android.skynavigator A/art﹕ art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:98]     51199: 0x356051e0 com.google.android.gms.clearcut.a.h
07-23 10:41:32.838   12180-6237/app.skynavigator.android.skynavigator A/art﹕ art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:98]     51198: 0x356051a0 com.google.android.gms.clearcut.a.h
07-23 10:41:32.838   12180-6237/app.skynavigator.android.skynavigator A/art﹕ art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:98]     51197: 0x35605160 com.google.android.gms.clearcut.a.h
07-23 10:41:32.838   12180-6237/app.skynavigator.android.skynavigator A/art﹕ art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:98]     51196: 0x35605120 com.google.android.gms.clearcut.a.h
07-23 10:41:32.838   12180-6237/app.skynavigator.android.skynavigator A/art﹕ art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:98]     51195: 0x356050e0 com.google.android.gms.clearcut.a.h
07-23 10:41:32.838   12180-6237/app.skynavigator.android.skynavigator A/art﹕ art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:98]     51194: 0x353c38a0 com.google.android.gms.clearcut.a.h
07-23 10:41:32.838   12180-6237/app.skynavigator.android.skynavigator A/art﹕ art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:98]     51193: 0x353c31e0 com.google.android.gms.clearcut.a.h
07-23 10:41:32.838   12180-6237/app.skynavigator.android.skynavigator A/art﹕ art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:98]     51192: 0x353c1120 com.google.android.gms.clearcut.a.h
07-23 10:41:32.838   12180-6237/app.skynavigator.android.skynavigator A/art﹕ art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:98]     51191: 0x353b7de0 com.google.android.gms.clearcut.a.h
```

The application works without any other problems, as soon as I remove the above mentioned lines of code.
And ideas, if google map is running into a problem doing those redraws on a polyline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should not remove and add a new polyline but just change its parameters!
You can change points, width, color etc of the polyline just keeping a reference to it!

> setColor(int color)
>
> setGeodesic(boolean geodesic)
>
> setPoints(List points)
>
> setVisible(boolean visible)
>
> setWidth(float width)
>
> setZIndex(float zIndex)

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polyline

it will be easier and better for performances!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It did solve my problem partially, as the performance is far better, than with redrawing the lines constantly. But the above problem still exists, but it takes much longer, until the message pops up and the application crashes.
It is quite interesting, that this application did work without such problems until about 2 months ago, when things started to go wrong. Could it be, that any update might cause this problem?

Comment: It is very difficult to say, because I feel it is something on the underlying gmaps api... Maybe there is something not released correctly by it. You should do memory profiling and check allocations

Comment: To be honest, until now, I did not use the memory profiling tool. I will invest some time, to get used to it and hopefully can find out something. At least, with your solution, the application is usable and working within the required time period.

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete global references to classes as well as to objects.